# Custom field days remaining to finish a task

Tags: ms-project

How can I create a formula that allows me, in a custom field, to calculate the remaining days of the task, with respect to the last data cutoff (Status Date), as long as it is not 100% complete?

I have tried to create a simple formula to perform the initial test of the remaining days, using the status date field and the end field, [End]-[Status Date], but the result is wrong.

Comment: Re *"...tried to create a simple formula"*: A good start could be to share that (but ****** ***not*** ****** [as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)).

Comment: Jhorbam, There is no "end" field in Project but there is a Finish field. Is that what you mean? What exactly is the formula your tried and which field did you customize with the formula? Also, you say the result is wrong. What is wrong about it? If you customized a Duration field (e.g. Duration1) with your formula and didn't account for proper conversion, the result could indeed be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "Remaining Duration" column that already exists in MS Project, it shows exactly what you are asking for.